# Obtaining a Non-Singular Matrix from a Singular one by Perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, singularity-theory

In a paper "http://www.math.cornell.edu/~nussbaum/papers/08-1.pdf" (page 264 Lemma 2) I encountered the following way of obtaining an invertible (non-singular) matrix from a non-invertible (singular) positive semi-definite one. Let matrix $A\geq0$ be non-invertible or singular and $I$ be the identity of the same order. Then we have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}A(A+xI)^{-1}=I$$

Why can such a limit be defined for a non-invertible matrix?

Comment: You can perturb a singular matrix by adding a small multiple of the identity, and get invertible matrices arbitrarily close to your original matrix. However why does that make you think your limit equation is true? Did they say that too where you were reading? To me the limit equation seems overly optimistic, and I would be surprised if it were always true (assuming $A$ is singular).

Comment: @user2566092 Thank you for your comment. So $A+xI$ is invertible for small $x$. What would be its inverse when $x$ goes to zero?

Comment: Can you share the name of this paper please? I cannot access it though the link provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion is never true.  If $A$ is a singular $n \times n$ matrix, there is a nonzero vector $v$ such that  $A v = 0$.  Then $A (A + xI)^{-1} v = (A + xI)^{-1} A v = 0$, so this can't converge to $Iv = v$ as $x \to 0$.

What is true is that if $0$ is not defective as an eigevalue of $A$, i.e. the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of $0$ as an eigenvalue of $A$ are equal, then the limit exists and is a projection on the range of $A$.

EDIT: The statement in the paper you referenced is patently wrong as written, but I believe the lemma can be rescued.  In this case $A$ is a hermitian matrix, so there are no defective eigenvalues, and the integral representation of $A^t$ for $0 < t \le 1$ is still correct.  It implies
$A^t v = 0$ for $v$ in the null space of $A$, which is indeed what you want.  The case $t=0$ might be somewhat problematic, and should be dealt with separately (what do you mean by $0^0$ anyway?).

EDIT: For the proof, if $0$ is not defective, then we can write the
vector space $A$ is acting on as $V = K \oplus R$, $K = \ker A$
 the kernel or null space, $R = \text{ran}\; A$ the range.  $K$ and $R$ are both invariant under $A$, so it suffices to look separately at what happens on $K$ and on $R$.  On $K$ of course we have $A (A+xI)^{-1} = 0$, as mentioned above.   Since the restriction $A_R$ of $A$ to $R$ is invertible, $(A_R + xI)^{-1} \to A_R^{-1}$ as $x \to 0$, and thus 
$A (A + xI)^{-1} v \to v$ for $v \in R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's say we have a $d$ dimensional Hilbert space and $A$ has $d'<d$ positive definite eigenvalues. The rest of the eigenvalues, corresponding to $m=d-d'$ eigenvectors are zero. Therefore we have $m$ zero eigenvalues corresponding to $m$ eigenvectors. Does that mean $A$ is not defective and the number of geometric and algebraic multiplicities of $0$ are equal? @Robert Israel

Comment: Also how could we prove the statement about matrices in which $0$ is not a defective eigenvalue?

Comment: That answers my question completely but still I would like to know how we could prove that in the case of matrices with no defective eigenvalues, the limit is well-defined. @Robert Israel

Comment: What is the justification for commuting $A$ and $(A+xI)^{-1}$?

Comment: By definition, any matrix commutes with its inverse, and so does the identity matrix, so $A = (A + x I) - xI$ commutes with $(A+xI)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

What if $A$ were the zero matrix? Then your limit would be the zero matrix. So your claim doesn't seem true, unless perhaps we make more assumptions on $A$.

Answer (score 0):

What is true is that $\det(A+xI)$ is a polynomial having a finite number of zeros. So for $x \neq 0$ small enough, $A+xI$ is invertible.

However, that doesn't mean that $A(A+xI)^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the inverse of the invertible matrix $A+xI$ for small enough $x$?

Comment: $(A+xI)^{-1}$ is the inverse.